# Watir-Webdriver: How to run headless, and in grid

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, automated-tests, headless-browser

I'm upgrading my script from Watir to Watir-Webdriver and I'm wondering how to take advantage of headless-browser testing and grid testing. I've done some research into it but my sources don't seem substantiated, and tutorials are very thin on the ground right now, so has anyone done headless browsing or grid testing? How did you achieve it, and what did you learn that you wish you knew when you started?

I'm working on XP and MS Server '03 VM machines. If I make progress on this I'll try to keep the question updated with information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Watir grid https://github.com/90kts/watirgrid might be what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I did consider WATiR grid, as well as selenium grid. I'm currently looking into how WATiR grid is best implemented, so pending the autobiography of a grid tester yours is the answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: It is something I am planning to look at for our web application, I would be interested on how you get on running your existing webdriver tests on a grid.

Comment: Cool, I'll try and keep my question updated with my progress, when I can make it

Answer (score 5):

I have written a post about how to run Watir-WebDriver heads headlessly using real web browsers in the cloud using Amazon EC2.

See: http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/29/running-your-watir-webdriver-tests-in-the-cloud-for-free/

Comment: I actually subscribe to your blog on google reader, but I didn't make the connection with my SO question :). Thanks muchly, though, I will be looking into it.